# Problem with CORS when rendering images from an iframe

Tags: iframe, cors, google-cloud-storage

Basically the thing is like this: I have a frontend where I render another frontend through an iframe, and in this iframe, I'm making requests to a bucket to fetch images and display them in my iframe (and therefore, in my frontend but through the iframe). The problem is that I'm encountering a CORS error, and I don't know how to solve it, since my bucket allows requests from both frontends.

This is the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/videos/video.m3u8' from origin 'https://frontend.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://iframe.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin

I read that this could be something related to communication between `<iframe>s`? I'm not really sure because I don't know what should interact between my iframes since I only render my videos in my iframe, not in my frontend. In my frontend, "I paste" my iframe and there I see the videos

Comment: An iframe's`src` (and, hence, its Web origin) may well be different from the page the iframe is embedded in.

Comment: @jub0bs Exactly, the origins are different. How can I ensure that only when I want to use my secondary frontend as an iframe, it can use the same origin as my primary frontend? Does this have to do with the Same Origin Policy?

Comment: Take the time to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @jub0bs I understand then that if my 2 micros have the same origin, for example: https://test.com, then my problem would be resolved? since the request has the same origin

Answer (score 3):

As @jub0bs told me, I read the documentation about Same Origin Policy and CORS, and indeed they were different origins. On the same [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), there is an example of when it will give an error and when it won't.

| URL | Outcome | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- |
| http://store.company.com/dir2/other.html | Same origin | Only the path differs |
| http://store.company.com/dir/inner/another.html | Same origin | Only the path differs |
| https://store.company.com/page.html | Failure | Different protocol |
| http://store.company.com:81/dir/page.html | Failure | Different port (http:// is port 80 by default) |
| http://news.company.com/dir/page.html | Failure | Different host |